# Calculating the average of a Variable value, android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a code in which the value is generated after every second depending on the users speed. Now i want the average values of all the generated speed values by the user. I want to display it in a textview.

How can i do it, any help?

Here is my code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    this.onLocationChanged(null);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (location == null) {

        tv.setText("0.0");
    } else {

        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        tv.setText(nCurrentSpeed + "");

    }
```

Now here nCurrentSpeed is the value generated every second, How can i get all the values that it generates and generate the average of all these contentiously.

Comment: Store those results in an array and calculate the average after every data acquisition.

Comment: Saves the sum of all the values, and the number of times the values have been updated, sum/count will be the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add 2 variables to your Activity?

```
private long startTime;
private float pointAverage;
```

Initalize those two in the Activities `onCreate()` method.

Now, you can modify your code

```
if (location == null) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        pointAverage = 0;
        actualizeTextField();
}
```

(This is your Start, right?)

```
else {
        pointAverage += location.getSpeed();
        actualizeTextField();
}
```

Finally add something like this

```
    public void actualizeTextField() {
        TextView tf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if(count > 0) {
            long timeOver = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            tf.setText(String.valueOf(pointAverage/(timeOver/1000)));
        } else {
            tf.setText("0.0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort man, last thing the value it is showing is not very precise. It shows a little bit low. You sure with the logic to calculate average?

Comment: You could also mesure the time instead if the count. I'll edit my answer. This should give you a value per second. Sorry for the Bad formatting, I'm writing this with my Nexus.

Comment: Bro Avg Speed is equal to total distance divided by total time. Can you format the answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
average speed = total distance / total time
```

So, all you need is to get the `total distance`.

You hold a variable to present the last `location`, called **preLocation**, and hold a variable to present the total distance, called **distance**,then try to add the codes in `onLocationChanged`:

```
distance += location.distanceTo(preLocation);
preLocation = location;
averageSpeed = distance / totalTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Record your recording start time `timeStart` and start Location `startLocation`;
2. Record your current time `timeCurrent` and current Location `currentLocation`;
3. Calculate your average speed:

   ```
   //your spend time
   int spendTime = timeCurrent - timeStart;
   //the distance
   float distance = currentLocation.distanceTo(startLocation)
   //your average speed
   averageSpeed = distance / spendTime
   ```