# Storing the highest value of the variable

Tags: android

I wrote a code which tells the speed of the user by using `GPS` location services. The speed is variable and I want to store the maximum speed attained and display it. My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  

    if (location == null) {
        tv.setText("0.0");
    } else {
        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        tv.setText(nCurrentSpeed + "");
    }   
}
```

Here `nCurrentSpeed` is a variable and I want to display its maximum value attained.

Comment: so you want to display maximum speed attained by per user right ?

Comment: @AkashShinde Yes bro

Comment: did you want this value for single app session or for all app session ?

Comment: @AkashShinde bro only for one app session. I got it right from the answer below.

Comment: @AkashShinde Could you be any help for me in [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727291/calculating-the-average-of-a-variable-value-android/29727416#29727416)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try in this way?

```
private Float nMaxSpeed = 0F;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (location == null) {
        // do something
    } else {
        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();

        if(nMaxSpeed < nCurrentSpeed) {
            nMaxSpeed = nCurrentSpeed;
        }
    }        

    tv.setText(nMaxSpeed.toString());
}
```

Using mMaxSpeed as field class variable and storing the currentSpeed every time its value is greater than the value currently stored in maxSpeed variable!